# IIS7 Manager: .NET Authorization is missing

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, authorization

I've got a Windows Server 2008 (With SP2) runing. My site works fine, but the IIS Manager (for IIS7) is missing the ".NET Authorization" icon to edit the site authorizations. The ".NET Authentication" icon shows up just fine, and I'm using Forms authentication. Other icons from the "Admin Pack" also show up, like FastCGI and HTTP Request Filtering.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This is a question for Serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is that you are either looking in the wrong place or don't have ASP.NET installed.  When I go to the iis manager by right clicking "My Computer" then selecting manage and navigating to IIS under "Services and Applications" it is the first icon in the list.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2b932a0cc1.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2b932a0cc1.jpg)

Notice it is in the ASP.NET settings and not the IIS Settings.

Note: This screen shot is from windows 7 not Windows server 2008.

Comment: It's most definately got ASP.NET installed, and configured. It has all the other .NET icons, and its running our .NET websites.

Comment: But that is definately the icon that is missing.