# Which IIS feature controls display of .NET Authorization?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I thought (and [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/113219/iis7-manager-net-authorization-is-missing) seems to confirm it) that .NET Authorization tab should be available whenever ASP.NET is installed. (If you also think this, please compare [this screenshot](http://pl.vc/19yqc) to find that this is obviously not the case.)

If you could provide a reason why it is not available, I would be grateful.

Our initial problem, which we hope to solve that way, is that calls to /api/MyApi are not routed to our application's MyApiController on the left server, although ASP.NET 4 is installed correctly and the handler entries are the same on both servers. Both servers use WIndows2008R2, btw.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that .NET Framework 4 installations can be very problematic with ASP.NET integration.  I usually remove ASP.NET, restart, the reinstall ASP.NET just be sure.

CD /D C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

aspnet_regiis.exe /ua

restart

aspnet_regiis.exe /i

restart

Of course you should first validate this on a test machine.

---

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis /?
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.17929
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


                                           -- ASP.NET REGISTRATION OPTIONS --

-i                     Install this version of ASP.NET and update IIS configuration at the root level to use this
                       version of ASP.Net.

-ir                    Install this version of ASP.NET, register only. Do not change any web applications to use this
                       version.

-iru                   Install this version of ASP.NET. If there are any existing applications that uses ASP.NET, it
                       will not change IIS configuration to use this version.

-enable                When -enable is specified with -i, -ir or -r, ASP.NET will be enabled in the IIS security
                       console (IIS 6.0 or later).

-disable               When -disable is specified with -i, -ir or -r, ASP.NET will be disabled in the IIS security
                       console (IIS 6.0 or later).

-s <path>              Install scriptmaps for this version at the specified path, recursively.
                       E.g. aspnet_regiis.exe -s W3SVC/1/ROOT/SampleApp1

-sn <path>             Install scriptmaps for this version at the specified path, non-recursively.

-r                     Install this version of ASP.NET and update scriptmaps at the IIS metabase root and for all
                       scriptmaps below the root. Existing scriptmaps are upgraded to this version regardless of the
                       original versions.

-u                     Uninstall this version of ASP.NET. Existing scriptmaps to this version are remapped to highest
                       remaining version of ASP.NET installed on the machine.

-ua                    Uninstall all versions of ASP.NET on the machine.

-k <path>              Remove all scriptmaps to any version of ASP.NET from the specified path, recursively (not
                       supported on Windows Vista and higher versions).
                       E.g. aspnet_regiis.exe -k W3SVC/1/ROOT/SampleApp1

-kn <path>             Remove all scriptmaps to any version ASP.NET from the specified path, non-recursively (not
                       supported on Windows Vista and higher versions).

-lv                    List all versions of ASP.NET that are installed on the machine, with status and installation
                       path.

-lk                    List all the path of all IIS metabase keys where ASP.NET is scriptmapped, together with the
                       version. Keys that inherit ASP.NET scriptmaps from a parent key will not be displayed (not
                       supported on Windows Vista and higher versions).

-c                     Install the client side scripts for this version to the aspnet_client subdirectory of each IIS
                       site directory.

-e                     Remove the client side scripts for this version from the aspnet_client subdirectory of each IIS
                       site directory.

-ea                    Remove the client side scripts for all versions from the aspnet_client subdirectory of each IIS
                       site directory.

-ga <user>             Grant the specified user or group access to the IIS metabase and other directories used by
                       ASP.NET.



                                         -- CONFIGURATION ENCRYPTION OPTIONS --

-pe section            Encrypt the configuration section. Optional arguments:
                       [-prov provider] Use this provider to encrypt.
                       [-app virtual-path] Encrypt at this virtual path. Virtual path must begin with a forward slash.
                       If it is '/', then it refers to the root of the site. If -app is not specified, the root
                       web.config will be encrypted.
                       [-site site-name-or-ID] The site of the virtual path specified in -app. If not specified, the
                       default web site will be used.
                       [-location sub-path] Location sub path.
                       [-pkm] Encrypt/decrypt the machine.config instead of web.config.

-pd section            Decrypt the configuration section. Optional arguments:
                       [-app virtual-path] Decrypt at this virtual path. Virtual path must begin with a forward slash.
                       If it is '/', then it refers to the root of the site. If -app is not specified, the root
                       web.config will be decrypted.
                       [-site site-name-or-ID] The site of the virtual path specified in -app. If not specified, the
                       default web site will be used.
                       [-location sub-path] Location sub path.
                       [-pkm] Encrypt/decrypt the machine.config instead of web.config.

-pef section web-app-physical-dir
                       Encrypt the configuration section. Optional arguments:
                       [-prov provider] Use this provider to encrypt.

-pdf section web-app-physical-dir
                       Decrypt the configuration section.

-pc container          Create an RSA keypair in ContainerName. Optional arguments:
                       [-size key-size] Key-size. Default is 1024.
                       [-pku] User container instead of machine container.
                       [-exp] Make the private keys exportable.
                       [-csp provider] Csp Provider to use.

-pz container          Delete the ContainerName. Optional arguments:
                       [-pku] User container instead of machine container.

-pi container file     Import an RSA keypair from the Xml file. Optional arguments:
                       [-pku] User container instead of machine container.
                       [-exp] Create exportable keys.
                       [-csp provider] Csp Provider to use.

-px container file     Export an RSA keypair to the Xml file. Optional arguments:
                       [-pku] User container instead of machine container.
                       [-pri] Include private keys.
                       [-csp provider] Csp Provider to use.

-pa container account  Add access for the account to the container. Arguments:
                       [-pku] User container instead of machine container.
                       [-csp provider] Csp Provider to use.
                       [-full] Add full access (default is Read access).

-pr container account  Remove access for the account from the container. Arguments:
                       [-pku] User container instead of machine container.
                       [-csp provider] Csp Provider to use.
```